# Can name() method be used in if tag

Tags: xslt-1.0

If the if condition is commented i get output as w:p, w:sec etc, which is exactly what i need. But with the if condition where only w:p should be allowed to print is not happening. Can any figure this out...

```
<xsl:param name="para" select="w:p"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

         <xsl:for-each select="node()/*/*">
            <xsl:if test = "name() = $para">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
```

**Input XML:**

```
<w:p>
<w:pPr></w:pPr>
</w:p>
<w:sec>
</w:sec>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is here**:

> ```
> <xsl:param name="para" select="w:p"/>
> ```

This attempts to select the child of the document node, named "w:p" not the string "w:p".

**Solution**:

Replace the above with:

```
<xsl:param name="para" select="'w:p'"/>
```